# using evalin to evaluate a function in the base workspace

Tags: matlab, function

I am trying to allow a function to have access to the base workspace using the evalin function, but I am having trouble. Here is a simple example:

My main code:

```
A = 1;

B = 2
evalin('base','[ C ] = FUN(B)');

C
```

My Function:

```
function [C ] = FUN( B )

     C = A + B;

end
```

My error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'A'.

Error in FUN (line 4)
C = A + B;

Error in Test (line 4)
evalin('base','[ C ] = FUN(B)');
```

So, the function is not being evaluated in the base workspace because it does not know what the value of A is.

Can anyone suggest something? I have a lot of variables that I need to access in several functions and I don't want to pass them and I don't want to use global variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [evalin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) documentation,

*evalin(ws, expression) executes expression, a string containing any valid MATLAB® expression, in the context of the workspace ws. ws can have a value of 'base' or 'caller' to denote the MATLAB base workspace or the workspace of the caller function.*

So the line of code

```
evalin('base','[ C ] = FUN(B)');
```

evaluates only the line of code

```
[ C ] = FUN(B)
```

in the context of the **base** workspace.  It does not evaluate the body of the function within the context of the **base** workspace.  So the error that you are observing makes sense.

Is there a particular reason why you don't want to pass the variables in to the function?  Why do you have several variables in the base (?) workspace, or do you just have several variables within a main function?

If the latter, you could use nested functions to have access to the variables declared in the caller (function) workspace.  For example, suppose you have a main function like

```
function main()

    A = 1;
    B = 2;

    C = FUN();

    function [C] = FUN()
        C = A + B;
    end
end
```

The function `FUN` has access to both `A` and `B` and so you don't have to pass in any arguments.

---

An alternative to passing in several different inputs, is to just pass in a structure that has different fields that your function can access at will.  Using the above example, we could do the following

```
function main()

    A = 1;
    B = 2;

    data.A = A;
    data.B = B;

    C = FUN(data);


end

function [C] = FUN(data)
    C = data.A + data.B;
end
```

In this case, the function `FUN` can be a function within its own file or declared after `main`.  Again, we only pass in one argument that has all the data that the function needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. I guess that the best policy is to store the data into a structure and then pass that structure to the function as you suggested. I am fairly new to coding and I am trying to develop good practices. Thanks again, I appreciate it very much!

Comment: @user3784721 actually namespaces are a common solution to this problem--similar to what you were trying. Using a struct to pass variables needed by e.g. local helper functions can get a bit clunky. Nested functions are ok if the helper functions are specific to one parent function's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Evalin function is used to take data from base workspace:

Syntax is :

```
evalin('base','variable')
```

Evalin function is used in the function .

For example see the below function

```
function [out1 out2 out3]=main_fun(in1,in2)
out1=in1+in2;
out2=in1-in2;
in3=evalin('base','in3');
in4=evalin('base','in4');
out3=in3+in4;

end
```

Here out3 value will have the sum of in3 and in4 from workspace.
out1 and out2 will have the sum and difference of in1 and in2 from current function workspace.